# how can I use sed to replace the lists that begins with (*) in a file

Tags: text-processing, sed

Using `sed` how can I replace the lines that start with a star and replace it with numbers starting from 1?

I need to replace the (*) in the fist of a list with numbers using sed for example >

this file contain a list

```
*linux

*computers

*labs

*questions
```

to >>>>

this file contain a list

```
1 linux
2 computers
3 labs
4 questions
```

I tried using

```
sed -e 's/*//' file.in > file.out | sed -i = file.out
```

Comment: "with numbers starting from 1", what do you mean by this? That each replaced line should contain a number incremented by one from the last replaced line? If so, you may want to consider `awk` rather than `sed`. Additionally, is this a homework question? What have you tried?

Comment: 1) [@Hauke Laging](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/32191/hauke-laging) is right. 2) what have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried to print the star first but i couldn't

Comment: I added numbers to your example output since you mention them but did not show them. Please make sure the output is what you want.

Answer (score 8):

You can use awk:

```
awk '/^\*/ {sub(/\*/, ++i)} 1' <<END
A list
* one
* two
Blah
* three
END
```

```
A list
1 one
2 two
Blah
3 three
```

Comment: I might be misunderstanding the OP, but I think he meant to replace the whole line, not just the star. Still though, `+1` for `awk`.

Answer (score 7):

You can play some trick - first number lines with `*` only then strip `*` and `spaces` if you want

```
nl -bp^[*] file | sed 's/^\s*\|\s*\*//g'
```

Answer (score 3):

I would use perl instead. The syntax for this is very simlar to `sed`'s:

```
perl -pe 's/^\*/$c++/e' file
```

Or, to start from 1:

```
perl -pe 's/^\*/++$c/e' file
```

And to edit the original file in place:

```
perl -i -pe 's/^\*/++$c/e' file
```

Comment: "Or, to start from 1:...", why not just `s/^\*/++$c/`?

Answer (score 3):

```
{   tr -s \\n |
    sed =|
    sed '$!N;s/\n./ /'
} <<\INPUT
*linux

*computers

*labs

*questions
INPUT
```

#### OUTPUT

```
1 linux
2 computers
3 labs
4 questions
```

`nl` is the most obvious, but `sed` can count lines. `sed` is not alone in that respect:

```
sh <<HD
$(sed -n 's/^\*\(.*\)/echo "$LINENO \1"/p' <infile)
HD
```

...or...

```
sed -n "s/..*/OUT='&'/p" <infile | 
PS1='${LINENO#0} ${OUT#?}${IFS#??}' dash -i
```

...both of which print the same as before *(even if it is a little silly)*. I use `dash` here explicitly because, by default, it does not enable any `readline` like terminal reader. If `dash` is your `sh` you can just use `sh`, but if `bash` is linked in to `sh` you'll need to use the `--noediting` for the second example to avoid it printing the `OUT=...` stuff to the terminal as well.

And really, for your simple example case, the entire thing can be done with `nl` and `tr`:

```
tr -d \* <<\INPUT| nl -s ' ' -w1 -nln
*linux

*computers

*labs

*questions
INPUT
```

#### OUTPUT

```
1 linux

2 computers

3 labs

4 questions
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't come up with a solution that uses only `sed`, but this comes close. It uses only `sed`, shell builtins, and `cmp` and `mv`. With some effort and a modern shell, you could rewrite this to hold the file contents in shell variables, and not have to use `cmp` or `mv`.

```
#!/bin/sh
if test $# -ne 1
then
    echo usage: $0 file
    exit 1
fi
num=1    # start numbering at 1
infile="$1"
outfile="$1.out"
mv "$infile" "$outfile"    # set up so initial cmp always fails
while ! cmp -s "$infile" "$outfile" # repeat the sed until no more ^* can be found
do
    mv "$outfile" "$infile"
    # replace the first occurrence of ^* with a number and a space
    sed '0,/^\*/s//'$num' /' "$infile" > "$outfile" 
    num=$(expr $num + 1)
done
rm "$outfile"
```

test:

```
$ cat i
first line
*second
*third
fourth
*fifth
$ ./change i
$ cat i
first line
1 second
2 third
fourth
3 fifth
```

Comment: Maybe an extra newline at the end?

Answer (score -3):

`sed` cannot do calculations thus this is not possible in a useful way.

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer. And it can be done using `sed`, perhaps not pure `sed`, but still. Could you at least offer an alternative?

Comment: @terdon Of course, "you can't" is an answer to "How can". And "not pure X" doesn't make much sense to me. That would apply to nearly every case. My answer was the first, and I expected the OP to react in a useful way i.e. "OK, an awk/perl/coreutils solution would do, too". Not my fault that he hasn't.

Comment: Instead of waiting for him to react, offer him an alternative right away -_-. If he doesn't want an alternative, it would've helped someone else that stumbles upon this question.

Comment: @HaukeLaging I know it's technically an answer which is why I haven't deleted it or converted it into a comment despite the _two_ "Not an answer" flags that have been raised against it. It's just a particularly unhelpful answer.  Next time, if you want the OP to react, post a comment, that's what they're for.